# WPF - How to share a single instance of a collection between ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, mvvm, global-variables

So I have a List of objects, lets call it CameraList, and I have one window called StructureWindow that displays the CameraList in a TreeView. Then I have another window called ViewerWindow that displays the CameraList in a grid. Each window has its corresponding ViewModels. Both ViewModels must use the same instance of CameraList. How do I achieve this? Where do I create the CameraList instance? How do I share it / access it from various ViewModels?

In my WinForms version of this application I create a static class that holds a static property, I instantiate the CameraList there and that's it. I can access it anywhere I want throughout the application.

But since I'm trying to migrate to WPF using MVVM pattern, I'm wondering what is the best practice to do this in WPF and MVVM?

[Here's what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY8E4.png)

Please kindly advise. Cheers guys.

Comment: use one model for different views

Comment: In the MVVM pattern you will have a data source (model) as a list of cameras. From this list you can create two separate viewmodels where one of them will have a hierarchical structure required by your tree view.

Comment: Hey anete, I cant do that, since each View already has a different ViewModel.

Comment: Hey Chrille, how do I do that without instantiating a new list of cameras for each ViewModel?

Comment: Either you bind to the exact same data structure, or you would need to sync the two viewmodels when there is a change. One way could be to keep the camera list in the data context of the window, and you could bind to it from both views.

Comment: @jbv_eng in MVVM no one prevents you to have two or more ViewModels that use the same Model, so put the cameraList in a model object and share it. If you use a framework you can also register the model as a singleton and pass the interface to the ViewModels constructor when you instantiate them

Comment: Thanks for replying Antonello. Okay so how do I put the cameraList in a model? and how do I share it? can you show some example?. Sorry for such basic questions. I'm very new in WPF and MVVM. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the camera list in a separate base viewmodel and set that to the datacontext of the window. This will allow you to bind to this data from both views using relative source binding:

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CameraList}"
```

Comment: Hey Chrille, what if I want to access that list from the ViewModels instead of XAML? How can I do that? I want the views to bind to the their respective ViewModels not to the parent window. Cheers.

Comment: I guess you could pass the list to the two separate view models when you create them then you could modify it from both view models and allow binding without using RelativeSource.